# How to select base token in CreateRestrictedToken to sandbox SYSTEM level services

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-services, sandbox

I am trying to sandbox SYSTEM level Win service in C++. In order to create the sandbox process, we first need to create a restricted token through CreateRestrictedToken which is then passed through CreateProcessAsUser.

CreateRestrictedToken needs a token of an existing process in input. At present, I was using the token of the current SYSTEM level process after dropping SIDs and priveledges. I read the following https://www.tiraniddo.dev/2020/01/dont-use-system-tokens-for-sandboxing.html and found that its not recommended to use SYSTEM level token as base token.

Where will I get the base token from?

Comment: Apparently, "SYSTEM" is allowed to do a service logon for "NETWORK SERVICE" and "LOCAL SERVICE". Use no password (i.e. `NULL`).

Comment: *All impersonate functions, including `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` allow the requested impersonation if one of the following is true:[document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-impersonateloggedonuser#remarks)*

Comment: As @ErykSun, the [LocalService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localservice-account) and [NetworkService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/networkservice-account) accounts are both predefined local accounts used by the service control manager. And they have minimum privileges on the local computer.

Comment: Our service needs to run in LocalSystem account due to which SeImpersonatePrivilege is enabled

Comment: Also, SeImpersonatePrivilege is enabled for LocalService too. The security vulnerability will exist in that too. @DrakeWu-MSFT

Comment: I did not suggest running your service as "LOCAL SERVICE". My suggestion requires that your service is running as "SYSTEM". Call `LogonUserW` to logon "NETWORK SERVICE" or "LOCAL SERVICE" with a service logon type and use the returned token to create a restricted token. Alternatively, you can use an S4U logon of a regular user account via `LsaLogonUser`, but that's much more involved than my first suggestion.

Comment: use `LogonUserW(L"*", L"*", L"*", LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken)` - `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` - new token already will be not have `AuthenticationId == SYSTEM_LUID`

Comment: @ErykSun got it. Still, "LOCAL SERVICE" won't work in my case as I need my sandboxed process to write to certain Read/Write EVERYONE folders which a "LOCAL SERVICE" token won't be able to do.

Comment: The access token created for the new "LOCAL SERVICE" logon contains S-1-1-0 (Everyone), S-1-5-32-545 (BUILTIN\Users) and S-1-5-11 (NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users) -- as well as other well-known groups including S-1-2-0 (LOCAL), S-1-2-1 (CONSOLE LOGON), S-1-5-6 (NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE), S-1-5-15 (NT AUTHORITY\This Organization), and also an SID for the new logon session of the form S-1-5-5-X-Y (NT AUTHORITY\LogonSessionId_X_Y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> its not recommended to use SYSTEM level token as base token.

for be more exactly its not recommended to use token with `AuthenticationId == SYSTEM_LUID`
(`SYSTEM_LUID` defined in *winnt.h* and *ntifs.h* as *{ 0x3e7, 0x0 }* )

for get token with another (not `0x3e7 = 999`) *AuthenticationId* you can simply call

`LogonUserW(L"*", L"*", L"*", LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken)`

then already call `CreateRestrictedToken` on returned token

Comment: Confirmed, this creates a new logon session with a new `LogonId` (i.e. the token `AuthenticationId`) instead of 999. Interestingly the new logon session uses "NT AUTHORITY" and "SYSTEM" for `AuthorityName` and `AccountName`, whereas logon-session 999 uses the machine authority and name, so the result of `GetUserNameExW(NameSamCompatible, ...)` changes to "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" in the context of the new token. Also, what do the `LogonUserW` docs mean by "[t]he new logon session has the same local identifier"? Are they talking about the `TokenUser` SID?

Comment: @ErykSun `SspiExGetUserName` check token `AuthenticationId` for `LUID LsapSystemLogonId = SYSTEM_LUID ` and if yes, jump to separate node. *new logon session has the same local identifier* - hard say what exactly this mean. most groups (except logon), user sid, privileges copied from current thread (or process) token

Comment: I don't see why `SspiExGetUserName` would need to special case `SYSTEM_LUID` in code when the `Token->LogonSession` record is already special cased to use the machine name in `AuthorityName` and `AccountName` instead of "NT AUTHORITY" and "SYSTEM".

Comment: Regarding the token groups, the new token does contain a few additional groups compared to the original token, but just expected groups for the logon context: S-1-2-1 (CONSOLE LOGON), S-1-5-4 (NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE), S-1-5-15 (NT AUTHORITY\This Organization), S-1-5-32-545 (BUILTIN\Users), S-1-5-32-559 (BUILTIN\Performance Log Users).

Comment: We need different OriginatingLogonSession and not just the logon session. Does this gets covered too? @ErykSun <br/>As per [this] (https://www.tiraniddo.dev/2020/01/dont-use-system-tokens-for-sandboxing.html), Where is OriginatingLogonSession coming from? The value is set when an API such as LogonUser is used and is set to the Authentication ID of the Token calling the API.

Comment: @Harsh *We need different OriginatingLogonSession and not just the logon session* - why and for what ?

Comment: @RbMm As mentioned in the website, the security check for Authentication Id is against the OriginatingLogonSession and not LogonSession.

Comment: @Harsh - *if the current Process Token's Authentication ID matches the Impersonation Token's OriginatingLogonSession ID then allow impersonation* - so checked *Authentication ID*. this must be not system luid. not *OriginatingLogonSession*

Comment: @Harsh - *Where is OriginatingLogonSession coming from?* from session, in which new logon created. as result *LocalSystem* tokens have 0x3e7 ( *SYSTEM_LUID* ) as *Authentication ID* and 0 as *OriginatingLogonSession ID*. usual user tokens have 0x3e7 (*SYSTEM_LUID*) as *OriginatingLogonSession ID* and some unique *Authentication ID*. with my code you will have the same - some unique *Authentication ID* and *SYSTEM_LUID* as *OriginatingLogonSession ID*

Comment: @Harsh - but look like you not undertand article. checked only **Process Token's Authentication ID**. what in process token *OriginatingLogonSession ID* not play role

Comment: @RbMm got it. I got confused between the process token and the impersonation token. Thanks!

Comment: @Harsh, I don't follow you. The access token returned by `LogonUserW` (et al) has its  `OriginatingLogonSession` set to the `AuthenticatonId` of the caller, so the caller is allowed to impersonate the token. It's an implicit creator right. ISTM that the point of the article was to highlight that a sandboxed access token that uses the builtin SYSTEM logon session, 0x3e7 (999), will still have its implicit right to impersonate tokens created from that logon session.